# GPU is idle most of the time when using tensorflow on windows

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, anaconda, nvidia

I am trying to use DeepLabV2 network on my windows PC. I have GTX 1080Ti (8GB), 32 GB RAM and core i7. I am training the network on cityscape dataset.

I am using conda/pip to install packages including tensorflow gpu. My NVIDIA driver and CUDA/cuDNN versions are all latest. I have also copied the CUDNN files from include and lib folder to my virtualenv from conda.

Below are some details on them:

[image: NVIDIA SMI OUTPUT]

[image]

My problem is I see CPU to be utitlized 100% during training but GPU is idle almost all the time. When I run the network, it can detect the GPU. See below:

[image]

I have limited the GPU ram to 6GB as the dataset was too heavy and forcing crash.

After the first loop:
[image]

The CPU and GPU utilization is shown below:

[image: GPU]

[image: CPU]

I read about profiling on internet, but usually bottleneck created from data results in more GPU idle time compared to CPU. But, here only CPU is used, GPU is just idle all the time.

What am I missing here? As far as I can see, GPU is configured correctly and recognised by conda env and tensorflow.

Thanks!

EDIT: numpy mkl output

[image]

Comment: Is the same code run on Linux and properly utilize GPU? Chances are the code is just badly written and things like NMS suppression are done in CPU.

Comment: Or maybe the numpy you're using doesn't have MKL?

Comment: I havent tried it on linux yet. The code is just cloned from this repo https://github.com/google-research/deeplab2.
I have added screenshot to list numpy versions. I think mkl is included, not sure though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. I wasnt supplying the following argument in the training script ´ --num_gpus=1´

Thus, gpu was never used. After I used it, GPU is used and training is done normally.